# How can I navigate in command prompt to a remote folder which has been shared among users?

Tags: windows, command-line, shared-folders

So basically I want to go to 192.xxx.xxx.xxx\myFolder to see the files in it.
I go with Explorer and it works fine, I can even delete and/or modify and add files to it.

The problem is that I'm trying to go through: 
`cd \\192.xxx.xxx.xxx\myFolder` 
and it returns:
CMD is not compatible with the UNC access routes as an actual directory (I'm translating this, as the original message is in spanish).

Hope this question makes sense,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Windows 7 my friend (although the folder is in Server 2003)  @EBGreen

Comment: On W7 you would have Powershell where you could CD to the UNC path with no problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use pushd to create a virtual drive:

```
pushd \\UNC\path
```

And to unmap the virtual drive and return to your previous local path:

```
popd
```

Comment: I gather [that works](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317379), but even for Microsoft, it's bizarre...

Comment: I suppose it makes sense because you can't just simply traverse into it. It has to mount the location to the filesystem first, and `pushd` can do so temporarily, pretty easily.

Comment: @BenRichards: Windows mounts disks and network shares as soon as they're accessed; assigning a drive letter is entirely optional. It's an artificial limitation in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @grawity Good point. And I'd say "compatibility with DOS" to that, except they already ditched any decent DOS compatibility with Vista. So, I suppose it really is bizarre.

Answer (score 7):

You can mount a network share to a drive letter and use this mount point in the command prompt. Obviously, you can mount through the graphical user interface, but also through the command line using the `net use` command, e.g.:

```
net use D: \\192.168.1.1\share && cd /D D:
```

Unmount using `net use D: /DELETE`. Consult `net use /?` for more flags, for instance if access to the share requires a password.